# 前処理の段階で、正規表現を使用して商品名を統一したい

Tags: python, 正規表現

Pythonにて、データ分析の勉強をしております。(Python初学者)

前処理の段階で、正規表現を使用して商品名を統一したいです。
実際の、商品名をみると、以下のように汚いです。

・あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-315円
・あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-345円
・あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-355円

全部、uniqueな「あらびきソーセージ」という同じ商品ですが、消費税等の変化により、商品名が別物としてあらわれている現状です。

「やりたいこと」
全て、「あらびきソーセージ」にしたい！！

```
data["商品名"] = data["商品名"].str.replace(" 正規表現 ", "あらびきソーセージ")
```

どのような正規表現をかけば、全てあらびきソーセージに変更できるのでしょうか？？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 末尾の「〇〇円」までを商品名とみなしているのであれば、この場合は単に「あらびきソーセージ」の文字列を含んでいるか、だけチェックすれば済んでしまいそうな気がします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます！

Comment: 最終的に、「あらびきソーセージ」という項目で売上データとのグラフを作成したいので、チェックだけではなく揃えて統一したいという背景があります。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サンプルコードの項番1のように、特定の文字列を部分的に含む商品名を置換したいだけならば、1行のコードで置換することができます。

サンプルコードの項番2のように、正規表現を使いたい場合は[`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/re.html#re.sub)で置換することができます。
`r"\g<1>"`はグループ番号を表し、1つ目の引数で(括弧)でくくられたグループに該当する文字列を意味します。

サンプルコードの項番3のように、pandas.DataFrameの要素を正規表現で置換したい場合は、`replace`の[`regex`引数をTrueにする](https://note.nkmk.me/python-pandas-replace/)ことで置換することができます。
こちらは質問文でpandasを使っていると推測されたので書き足しています。pandasをpip installしていないとエラーになります。

```
items = [
    "あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-315円",
    "あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-345円",
    "あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-355円",
    "薫香あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-455円",
    "あらさがしソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-355円",
]

# 1. 内包表記で"あらびきソーセージ"を含む表現を"あらびきソーセージ"に置換する
n = ["あらびきソーセージ" if "あらびきソーセージ" in s else s for s in items]
print(n) # ['あらびきソーセージ', 'あらびきソーセージ', 'あらびきソーセージ', 'あらびきソーセージ', 'あらさがしソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-355円']

# 2. 正規表現で"あらびきソーセージ"を含む表現を"あらびきソーセージ"に置換する
import re

n = []
for s in items:
    n.append(re.sub("^.*(あらびきソーセージ).*$", r"\g<1>", s))

print(n) # ['あらびきソーセージ', 'あらびきソーセージ', 'あらびきソーセージ', 'あらびきソーセージ', 'あらさがしソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-355円']

# 3. データフレームで正規表現置換する
import pandas as pd

json = '''
[
    {"id": 1, "商品名": "あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-315円"},
    {"id": 2, "商品名": "あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-345円"},
    {"id": 3, "商品名": "あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-355円"},
    {"id": 4, "商品名": "薫香あらびきソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-455円"},
    {"id": 5, "商品名": "あらさがしソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-355円"}
]
'''

data = pd.read_json(json)
data = data.replace("^.*(あらびきソーセージ).*$", r"\g<1>", regex=True)
print(data)

""" 
   id                        商品名
0   1                  あらびきソーセージ
1   2                  あらびきソーセージ
2   3                  あらびきソーセージ
3   4                  あらびきソーセージ
4   5  あらさがしソーセージ-135Ｇ/6本入り-355円
"""
```

Comment: ありがとうございます！！様々なパターンを想定して回答してくださり、勉強になりました。今後、データ処理系のことをする際に、「正規表現」を扱えると楽になると考えているのですが、正規表現に関してオススメの勉強プラクティスなどがあれば教えていただきたいです。

Comment: 解決済みマークの承認等ありがとうございます。私はpythonの正規表現は独学ですので有用性は不明ですが、オライリーの[詳説 正規表現](https://www.oreilly.co.jp/books/9784873113593/)は基本から応用まで網羅的に書かれているのでお勧めです。正規表現は(わりと|かなり)?手軽に始められるスキルですので[,、 ]*一通り構文を眺めた後は実践練習することが一番の勉強プラクティスではないでしょうか。がんばってください！{1,}

Comment: ありがとうございます！早速購入してみました。頑張ります。